# How to rename a file to a variable?

Tags: python, operating-system, rename, python-3.5

Currently in my program, it creates a temp file and saves it. I would like to rename this temp file to the value of a variable (in this example, fileName), but I am getting an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp' -> 'fileName'.

The function code goes as follows:

```
    fileName = input(FileNameText)
exist = os.path.isfile(fileName)
if exist == True:
    print("This file name already exists.")
    while True:
        try:
            overWrite = ("Would you like to overwrite the file? Y = yes, N = no\n")
            if overWrite == "Y":
                break
            if overWrite == "N":
                export()
            else:
                invalidInput()
        except:
            invalidInput()
    os.rename("temp",fileName)
if exist == False:
    os.rename("temp",fileName)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `except` block catching? You should *always* be explicit and on't leave it naked.

Comment: If the file wasn't found, the file wasn't found. Your computer's files aren't visible to us, so we can't tell you what file you should be looking for.

Comment: `os.rename` arguments should be `(source, destination)`. The file 'temp' does not exist. It is not created in this code, so I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Comment: The except block should be a ValueError... forgot to put it in!

Comment: No worries - very stupid mistake. Didn't add the +".txt" on the end as it didn't recognise the file name otherwise. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, line 9 `overWrite = ("Would you like to overwrite the file? Y = yes, N = no\n")` produces a one-item tuple. Should probably be `overWrite = input("Would you like to overwrite the file? Y = yes, N = no\n")`

Comment: @MatthewCole: No tuple, just a string. A one-element tuple has to be written as `(thing,)` instead of `(thing)`. We do need to call `input`.

Comment: @user2357112, oh you're right. Good call. That comma in the middle tripped me up when I was reading it fast.